# Why is my UITableView's separatorStyle being overridden by UIKit?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'm creating a `UITableView` programmatically, within a custom `UIView` subclass which itself is initialised from a XIB.

This is the code I'm using to configure and setup the table view - it is called from within `-initWithCoder:`:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
[self addSubview:self.tableView];
```

Once the view is actually shown on the screen, however, the table view's `.separatorStyle` has been changed to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`. By setting a breakpoint on `-[UITableView setSeparatorStyle:]`, I was able to observe that *after* the view containing the table view is added into the on-screen view hierarchy (after the above code was executed), UIKit itself resets this property, with the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x000000018829200c in -[UITableView setSeparatorStyle:] ()
#1  0x00000001834c7430 in __invoking___ ()
#2  0x00000001834c4fb4 in -[NSInvocation invokeUsingIMP:] ()
#3  0x00000001888d828c in __workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget_block_invoke ()
#4  0x00000001884b7c9c in +[UIView _performSystemAppearanceModifications:] ()
#5  0x00000001883422b0 in workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget ()
#6  0x00000001888d3540 in applyInvocationsToTarget ()
#7  0x00000001888d295c in +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:onlySystemInvocations:] ()
#8  0x00000001884c833c in __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke ()
#9  0x00000001884c82b4 in -[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] ()
#10 0x00000001881d46b4 in -[UIScrollView _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] ()
#11 0x00000001884f92c0 in -[UITableView _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] ()
#12 0x00000001884c81d0 in -[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] ()
#13 0x00000001881af044 in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#14 0x00000001881d4568 in -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#15 0x00000001881aed7c in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#16 0x00000001881aed7c in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#17 0x00000001881ae310 in __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke ()
#18 0x00000001881ae178 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] ()
#19 0x00000001881bbb80 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] ()
#20 0x00000001883ad600 in -[_UIParallaxDimmingView didMoveToWindow] ()
#21 0x00000001881af05c in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#22 0x00000001881aed7c in -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] ()
#23 0x00000001881ae310 in __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke ()
#24 0x00000001881ae178 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] ()
#25 0x00000001881bbb80 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] ()
#26 0x000000018844ddb4 in __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#27 0x00000001881c2964 in +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] ()
#28 0x00000001883ad118 in __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke ()
#29 0x00000001884c8840 in +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] ()
#30 0x00000001883acc90 in -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] ()
#31 0x00000001883666a0 in -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] ()
#32 0x00000001882729b8 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#33 0x0000000188272694 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#34 0x00000001882725fc in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#35 0x00000001881af778 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#36 0x0000000185bbeb2c in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#37 0x0000000185bb9738 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#38 0x0000000185bb95f8 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#39 0x0000000185bb8c94 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#40 0x0000000185bb89dc in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#41 0x00000001881b2944 in _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue ()
#42 0x0000000183478efc in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#43 0x0000000183478990 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#44 0x0000000183476690 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#45 0x00000001833a5680 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#46 0x00000001848b4088 in GSEventRunModal ()
#47 0x000000018821cd90 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing UIKit to do this? I'd sure love to know what `workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget` refers to. :-)

This issue was observed on iOS 9.2.1.

Comment: I have same issue with the backgroundColor :(